# What is a non commital approach to software analysis

Tags: systems-analysis

When I think about software analysis the first thing which comes to mind is SSADM and the UML.

But, what I want is a high level view of the system before I commit to a programming paradigm.

Where am I going wrong?

How do I approach a problem in a high level and generic way before I commit to a paradigm?

What are the diagrams/tools available to support me?

Edit:

Some examples of tools that appear to be what I'm after are...

A block diagram - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_diagram

A data flow diagram - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram

Comment: did you consider using natural language? Some of the best _high level views of the system_ I've seen were using that kind er... tool to present a problem in a _high level and generic way_ before committing to particular paradigm

Comment: I would consider it but I find I am more quickly bogged down with the nitty gritty than I am enlightened.

Answer (score 1):

UML offers a variety of diagrams to model your system for various purposes.

The first and foremost aspect of the software to re-engineer or to engineer a software for the required system is the overall Business Scenario (what objectives and goals the software/system should meet). The formal phrase for such requirements is "**Business Requirements**".

Then comes the requirements, the intended users of the system should be able to meet to achieve the objectives. These are called "**User Requirements**".

You can model User Requirements in UML by using [Use-Case Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_Case_Diagram). This modeling should be prior to your functional (this includes DFD, ERD) and non-functional requirements (environment, constraints, platform, sclability).